# Why does a route trigger early with $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I have set up

```
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/terms', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/terms/terms.html',
            controller: 'TermsController'
        })
        .when('/patients/:patientId/schedule/daily', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/schedule/schedule.html',
            controller: 'ScheduleHomeController'
        })
        .when('/patients/:patientId/schedule/complex', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/schedule/schedule.html',
            controller: 'ScheduleHomeController'
        })
        .when('/error', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/error.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/error'
        });
```

I have some links:

```
            <li class="anchor" data-ng-class="{'current-pg':model.schedulePage==='daily-schedule'}">
                <a href="#/patients/{{ model.currentPatient.patientId }}/schedule/daily">Daily</a>
            </li>
            <li data-ng-class="{'current-pg':model.schedulePage==='complex-schedule'}">
                <a href="#/patients/{{ model.currentPatient.patientId }}/schedule/complex">Complex</a>
            </li>
```

When I click `Complex`, the `HomeController` gets triggered for some reason.

```
window.map.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'cache',
    function($scope, $location, cache) {
console.trace();
```

That `trace` gets triggered:

```
[Log] console.trace()
    (anonymous function) (app.src.js, line 6110)
    invoke (vendor.src.js, line 29750)
    instantiate (vendor.src.js, line 29758)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.src.js, line 34048)
    link (vendor.src.js, line 52831)
    invokeLinkFn (vendor.src.js, line 33805)
    nodeLinkFn (vendor.src.js, line 33315)
    compositeLinkFn (vendor.src.js, line 32664)
    publicLinkFn (vendor.src.js, line 32543)
    boundTranscludeFn (vendor.src.js, line 32682)
    controllersBoundTransclude (vendor.src.js, line 33342)
    update (vendor.src.js, line 52789)
    $broadcast (vendor.src.js, line 40332)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.src.js, line 52472)
    processQueue (vendor.src.js, line 38795)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.src.js, line 38811)
    $eval (vendor.src.js, line 40013)
    $digest (vendor.src.js, line 39829)
    $apply (vendor.src.js, line 40118)
    done (vendor.src.js, line 35245)
    completeRequest (vendor.src.js, line 35435)
    requestLoaded (vendor.src.js, line 35376)
```

Any reason why that would be?

Comment: Which HomeController route is being triggered? /error or /? if it is /error then maybe your hash path isnt being generated correctly and therefore does not match the route, and so triggering the otherwise route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, the click is not handled by AngularJS, but picked up later when AngularJS detects a hash change. To fix this, you should use `ng-href` instead of `href`, and omit the `#/` part. AngularJS will rewrite your links to start with `#/`.

```
   <li class="anchor" data-ng-class="{'current-pg':model.schedulePage==='daily-schedule'}">
        <a ng-href="patients/{{ model.currentPatient.patientId }}/schedule/daily">Daily</a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'current-pg':model.schedulePage==='complex-schedule'}">
        <a ng-href="patients/{{ model.currentPatient.patientId }}/schedule/complex">Complex</a>
    </li>
```